# Bootstrap navbar with collapsed menu icon - How to?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

On this bootstrap starter template:

[image]

when the browser gets narrow the navigation bar links/buttons collapse into one icon in top-right corner like this:

[image]

I would like to have this collapsed "icon" as default like on the picture above. So that the navbar links are available after the user clicks that top-right collapsed button.

How to do that?

This is the source code of the template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all in the CSS.

See this post and check out the css column.

[Always Collapse Bootstrap Nav](http://www.bootply.com/114896)

Working Example:

```css
.navbar .navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Always make it a point to add code to your answers; external links can break leaving your answers less meaningful (if not meaningless).

Comment: ok.  Thanks for the info @vanburen.  I'll do that from now on!